# Django, cordova and authentication

Tags: django, cordova, jquery-mobile, django-rest-framework

I have a backend in Django +allauth, rest framework and native app in cordova/jquery mobile. I have to access login/logout page in this native app.

I'm a little confused with that.
I make simple ajax to test it.

I added

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url+"login/",
    data : {x:'user1', y:"pass1"}
})
```

I created in my django db this model (user1, pass1)

And I have view in Django

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def login(request):
    username = request.POST.get('x')
    password = request.POST.get('y')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(user)
return Response({...})
```

But in line

```
login(user)
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'encoding'
```

When I put print after

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
print user
```

I get this user "user1"

Dou you guys have anu ideas how correctly make this login system?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. Just rename function to something other than 'login'.

Comment: The call `login(user)` would have been recursively calling the function which it is inside. Alternatively the import `from django.contrib import auth` would allow the call `auth.login(user)`, as an alternative fix to the namespace clash.

Comment: Plus doesn't the login function require the request? `login(request, user)`

Answer (score 0):

Since I believe you are using Django Rest Framework, here is a class based function to login (ignore the token side if you want, but I am assuming you are also using tokens or something like that.

```
class APILoginViewSet(APIView):
    """
    View to list all users in the system.

    * Requires token authentication.
    """

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = LoginCustomSerializer(data=data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            email = serializer.data.get('email')
            password = serializer.data.get('password')

            if not request.user.is_anonymous():
                return Response('Already Logged-in', status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

            account = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

            if account is not None:
                if account.is_active:
                    login(request, account)

                    # Add the token to the return serialization
                    try:
                        token = Token.objects.get(user=account)
                    except:
                        token = Token.objects.create(user=account)

                    data = {
                      'token': token.key
                    }

                    return Response(data)
                else:
                    return Response('This account is not Active.', status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
            else:
                return Response('Username/password combination invalid.', status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and in your serializer.py

```
class LoginCustomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=200)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
```